# Error al cargar `lang/es.js`

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

Estoy tratando de traducir el calendario que se origina de la librería `fullcalendar.js`. Para eso agregué `lang/es`. Sin embargo, me devuelve el siguiente error en la consola:

```
a.fullCalendar.datepickerLang is not a function
```

Adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```js
/* CALENDAR */
function  init_calendar() {
  
if( typeof ($.fn.fullCalendar) === 'undefined'){ return; }
console.log('init_calendar');
  
var date = new Date(),
  d = date.getDate(),
  m = date.getMonth(),
  y = date.getFullYear(),
  started,
  categoryClass;

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
    },

    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      $('#fc_create').click();

      started = start;
      ended = end;

      $(".antosubmit").on("click", function() {
        var title = $("#title").val();
        if (end) {
          ended = end;
        }

        categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

        if (title) {
          calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            title: title,
            start: started,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay
          },
            true // make the event "stick"
          );
        }

        $('#title').val('');
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        $('.antoclose').click();

        return false;
      });
    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      $('#fc_edit').click();
      $('#title2').val(calEvent.title);

      categoryClass = $("#event_type").val();

      $(".antosubmit2").on("click", function() {
        calEvent.title = $("#title2").val();

        calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
        $('.antoclose2').click();
      });

      calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },

    editable: true,
    events: [{
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }, {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
      end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
    }, {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 14, 12, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      start: new Date(y, m, 28),
      end: new Date(y, m, 29),
      url: 'http://google.com/'
    }]
    
  });
  
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  init_calendar();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Gentelella Alela! | </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link href="../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- NProgress -->
  <link href="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- FullCalendar -->
  <link href="../vendors/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../vendors/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
  
  <!-- Custom styling plus plugins -->
  <link href="../build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="nav-md">

<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="">
    <div class="page-title">
      <div class="title_left">
        <h3>Calendar <small>Click to add/edit events</small></h3>
      </div>

      <div class="title_right">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="x_panel">
          <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Calendar Events <small>Sessions</small></h2>
            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
              <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
              
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="x_content">
            <div id='calendar'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /page content -->

<!-- footer content -->
      
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>

<!-- NProgress -->
<script src="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>

<!-- FullCalendar -->
<script src="../vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<!--este me causa error en la imagen, para que traduzca el calendario-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../vendors/fullcalendar/dist/lang/es.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
<script src="../build/js/custom.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ese es todo el código que utilizo para generar el calendario. La versión que estoy utilizando es la de **FullCalendar v3.1.0**. Utilicé los archivos que recomiendan en su [Página Oficial](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/locale), que es `es.js` y llamarlo con un `script`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../vendors/fullcalendar/dist/lang/es.js"></script>
```

Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Hola elber, esta pregunta es algo amplia, por favor edítala para añadir más información: ¿qué versión de FullCalendar estás usando? ¿cómo incorporas los ficheros en el proyecto? ¿Puedes crear un  [mcve] en la propia pregunta para que podamos  ver  el problema? (o al menos compartir el código). Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: La versión que estoy usando es la de FullCalendar v3.1.0, use los archivos que recomiendan en su pagina oficial, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/locale, que es agregar el archivo es.js y llamarlo con un script :<script src='fullcalendar/locale/es.js'></script>

Comment: Por favor, añade tu código en la pregunta para que podamos verlo y detectar un posible problema. Una captura del error no es suficiente para ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias alvaro, alli agregue el código espero que la comunidad pueda ayudarme para que se pueda ejecutar y así traducir el calendario en cuestión, y gracias por las sugerencias.

Comment: Hay un error al final del javascript porque no está bien cerrado (te faltan el paréntesis y el punto y coma final): `$(document).ready(function() { init_calendar(); });`

Comment: Es verdad estaba mal cerrado en esa sección, fue un error mio al copiar y pegar, en mi código del proyecto si esta competo.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución Real**: Se debe actualizar a la última versión del Fullcalendar y/o jQuery/UI.

**Solución Alternativa**: Traducir los títulos manualmente.

```
$('#calendar-group').fullCalendar({
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    buttonText: {
        today:    'Hoy',
        month:    'Mes',
        week:     'Semana',
        day:      'Día',
        list:     'Lista'
    }

});
```